# Aligning an image to the left with div's to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues making the image float to the right whilst the rest of text and the div float to the right.

I can get it to work with a fixed width image but then if I swap the image for a slightly different size it won't work as I'm using fixed sizes. Is there a way for it to work when I don't know the size of the image? Or would I need to use JS for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/agcH5/

```
<div style="width:900px">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Course Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TyQ45nk.jpg">
        <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed porttitor diam. Quisque fermentum orci sed velit lacinia, nec vehicula eros consequat. Morbi vestibulum convallis auctor.</p>
        <div class="container-fluid row">
            <div class="col-md-9" style="padding: 0">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
                        80%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Continue</a>
            </div>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `div` do you want to float to right ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply make use of the boostrap's grid classes properly.
I edited the code in your div with class **panel-body**

```
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src='http://i.imgur.com/TyQ45nk.jpg'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed porttitor diam. Quisque fermentum orci sed velit lacinia, nec vehicula eros consequat. Morbi vestibulum convallis auctor.</p>
        <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
                        80%
                    </div>
                </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Continue</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/gamaj/1/

Comment: Like I said above, thanks for the answer but I also want the progress bar to the be on the right of the image

Answer (score 0):

You can try using either CSS or an inline style attribute:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TyQ45nk.jpg" style="float:right">
```

if you don't want words on the same line as the image, you can add the 'clear:right' attribute as well.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my self clear enough but I also want the progress bar div to be on the right of the image with the text

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` to `image`

```
.panel-body img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;   
}

.rightContent{
    margin-left: 380px;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/agcH5/5/)

Comment: Same as above I also want the progress bar to be on the right of the picture

Comment: The all content is goes right side of the image, have you checked the demo? Check this new Demo http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/agcH5/4/